# Several Days disabled in Calendar Component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hope you're all doing good guys!

I've been working on a calendar challenge in ReactJS and am facing an issue I really can't understand, I'm fetching days from a local API where I'm using an if Statement where if the current day of the month equals the day in the JSON file or less than that number then return an enabled button, else return disabled.

Here is the issue I'm facing:
[image: These Days are Disabled]
The days from 3 to 9 are disabled but I want them to be enabled as I wish for the user to be able to click on them. The days counting after the 25th to the 31st are disabled which is the desired output but somehow it messed up and took the former days as well from the 3rd til 9th.

Here is the code I'm working with:
[image: If Condition in ReactJS]

Here is the code in text format:

```
if (date >= day.day) {
      return (
        <Grid item key={day.id}>
          <Button
            key={day.id}
            sx={{
              color: 'white',
              width: 150,
              height: 150,
              backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
              '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
                opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
              },
            }}
          >
            {day.day}
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Grid item key={day.id}>
          <Button
            // Disabled attribute for the days that haven't passed
            disabled
            key={day.id}
            sx={{
              color: 'white',
              width: 150,
              height: 150,
              backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
              '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
                opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
              },
            }}
          >
            {day.day}
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
```

Here is the code for getting the date:
[image: Getting the date]

Here is an example of the API I'm fetching:
[image: JSON Object]

Here it is again in code format:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "day": "1",
    "chocolateImage": "https://sugarfreelondoner.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/keto-milk-chocolate-150x150.jpg"
  },
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Am I doing something wrong in the code?

Thanks for any answer in advance and take care guys

Comment: Can you update your post with an example of the API response and what `date` is in your code is?

Comment: @BojanIvanac Absolutely, I'll add it to the question

Comment: @BojanIvanac Thank you by the way for taking your time

Comment: No worries. Can you also share what `date` is in your code?

Comment: @BojanIvanac Absolutely, I added that too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need the `if/else` statement since the only thing that changes is the `disabled` prop.

You can just do this:

```
        <Grid item key={day.id}>
          <Button
            disabled={date <= day.day}
            key={day.id}
            sx={{
              color: 'white',
              width: 150,
              height: 150,
              backgroundColor: 'primary.dark',
              '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
                opacity: [0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
              },
            }}
          >
            {day.day}
          </Button>
        </Grid>
```

The second thing is, in your code for `date` you have a trailing `/`. That will cause issues. `const date = ${current.getDate()}/` can just be `const date = current.getDate()`

Try removing the trailing `/` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much man, it worked! Much appreciated for taking your time to help me out :D

Comment: Glad I could help @MustafaSaidHelal